# Shell program not executing when using server name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, shell, cmd

I have a VB.Net 2012 web application where we are trying to execute a process which starts a vbs script located on a Remote VM.

The code works properly when I run it directly within the Visual Studio debugger, which spawns via the following URL:

http://localhost:63579/DDFE/MultiRun.aspx?&Sort=

However when we publish the application to the production folder and run the web app the cmd process does not seem to be executed properly.  Below is the published URL:

http://ne1dwgtqa301/DDFE/MultiRun.aspx?&Sort=

You can see that the difference is in the machine name of "ne1dwgtqa301" vs "localhost:63579".

I assume this is a permissions issue but have been unable to determine the root cause of the Shell command not executing properly when run via the published URL.  This does not run even when executed on the host server, but the command works properly when run manually or via "localhost:63579" on the same server.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
Protected Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click
    Dim shellCommand As String

    For Each item As ListItem In lstVMs.Items
        If item.Selected = True Then
            shellCommand = "C:\websites\prod\DDFE\Log\psexec.exe \\NE1-VDI-" & item.Text & ".us.ad.xxx.com -e -h -u W2KXXX\user -p pswd C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /c C:\windows\SysWoW64\cscript.exe C:\Scripts\Driver.vbs"
            Shell(shellCommand, AppWinStyle.Hide)
        End If
    Next
End Sub     'btnRun_Click
```

Comment: what is the powershell.exe for after the -p pswd? ... is it supposed to start power shell before executing csscript.exe? ... I guess give me the order of operations... run psexec.exe input "\\NE1-VDI-" & item.Text & ".us.ad.xxx.com -e -h -u W2KXXX\user -p pswd" ... then run powershell... then run csscript with driver.vbs as the input

Comment: The 3rd post from the bottom here is describing the same issue I am having.  Is there a way to execute this code through java script that might work better?        https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/729598-asp-net-code-run-vbs-file

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark - but this is how I would write the shell command line.

```
        shellCommand = "cmd.exe /c cd C:\websites\prod\DDFE\Log\ " & "& psexec \\NE1-VDI-" & item.Text & ".us.ad.xxx.com -e -h -u W2KXXX\user -p pswd & powershell.exe /c cd C:\windows\SysWoW64\ " & "& cscript C:\Scripts\Driver.vbs"
        Shell(shellCommand, AppWinStyle.Hide, true, -1)
```

I think you are missing a crucial "&" symbol between your cmd.exe and powershell.exe commands

Comment: I am not quite sure what the "&" you added is trying to accomplish.  The original command I posted works properly when kicked off via Start ..> Run.  It is also working properly when run in debug mode on the localhost.   The "&" you added above is in the middle of the fully qualified path, and just causes the command to error out due to incorrect syntax.  Any other ideas?

Comment: did you try the above command without the "&" in the middle? honestly this is impossible to trouble shoot because I cant run the commnds... I personally would be using cmd though to troubleshoot and not Start>Run

Comment: yes I used cmd, as stated in the original post the commands work properly, it seems to be a permission issue.

Comment: ohh haha, I think I know ... On VS there is an tab in the project properties called "Security" - make sure that the option to run it as "Full Trust Application" is checked.

Comment: I see where the Project Properties are in VS 2012.  However I see no Security tab.  I have read where it should be, but am not seeing it for some reason.  I am unable to post pictures yet.   The only tabs I see are:  References, Build, Accessibility, MSBuild Options, Silverlight Applications.

Comment: Probably not seeing it because as stated above, this is a WEB application.